# Can I avoid mutating in this scenario?

Tags: scala

I am trying iterate an list and then doing an range check on each item and cumalating scores accordingly.

Pretty straight forward. I feel like i am doing this in more traditional way and creating lot of "var" variables..

Is there an effective functional/immutable way of achieving this behavior?

```
  var score_1 = 0
  var score_2 = 0
  var score_3 = 0
  var score_4 = 0
  var score_5 = 0

  val list = List(1,1,1,0.8,0.75,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.25,0.2,0.15,0.1)

  list.foreach( i => {
      i.toDouble match {
        case x if( x == 1.0 ) => score_1 += 1
        case x if( x >= 0.75 && x < 1 ) => score_2 += 1
        case x if( x >= 0.50 && x < 0.75) => score_3 += 1
        case x if( x >= 0.25 && x < 0.50) => score_4 += 1
        case x if( x >= 0 && x < 0.25 ) => score_5 += 1
        case _ => 
      }
    })

 println(score_1,score_2,score_3,score_4,score_5)
```

Comment: You only need one condition in each `case` because the upper bound will have already been tested by the previous `case` : e.g. `if x >= 1`, `if x >= 0.75`, `if x >= 0.5` etc.

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks for pointing that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve immutability using `foldLeft`,

```
case class Score(score1: Int,
                 score2: Int,
                 score3: Int,
                 score4: Int,
                 score5: Int,
                 score6: Int,
                 score7: Int,
                 score8: Int)

object Score {
  def empty = new Score(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
}

val myScore = list.foldLeft(Score.empty) {
  case (score, 1.0)                       => score.copy(score1 = score.score1 + 1)
  case (score, x) if x > 0.75 && x < 1    => score.copy(score2 = score.score2 + 1)
  case (score, 0.75)                      => score.copy(score3 = score.score3 + 1)
  case (score, x) if x > 0.50 && x < 0.75 => score.copy(score4 = score.score4 + 1)
  case (score, 0.50)                      => score.copy(score5 = score.score5 + 1)
  case (score, x) if x > 0.25 && x < 0.50 => score.copy(score6 = score.score6 + 1)
  case (score, 0.25)                      => score.copy(score7 = score.score7 + 1)
  case (score, x) if x >= 0 && x < 0.25   => score.copy(score8 = score.score8 + 1)
  case (score, _)                         => score
}

println(myScore) // Score(3,1,1,2,1,1,1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that takes advantage of the fact that the score breakpoints are evenly spaced:

```
val scores = Array.fill(5)(0)

list.foreach{ x =>
  val bucket = math.floor(x*4).toInt

  scores(bucket) += 1
}
```

This uses a mutable `Array` but is probably the most efficient solution in this particular case.